# How does await works in async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function getName() {
    const abcd = await getTime();
    console.log("World");
}

function getTime() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Hello, ");
        }, 1000);
    })
}

getName();
```

I expected that after one second Hello, then World prints, unfortunately the output is only Hello, why?

Comment: You never `resolve()` the promise, so it waits until never.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Can you explain the operations that JS did under the hood in my code?

Comment: It simply translates the `async`/`await` syntax to `function getName() {
    return getTime().then(abcd => { console.log("World"); });
}`. No magic, just promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you `resolve` the `Promise` the `getTime` function will never return.

Therefore `await getTime()` will never resolve and will be forever waiting for a response.

If you call `resolve()` after the `console.log` then `getTime` will resolve, and therefore the `getName` function can continue on to console log "World".

```
async function getName() {
    const abcd = await getTime();
    console.log("World");
}

function getTime() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Hello, ");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    })
}

getName();
```

Comment: _the function will never return_ what do you mean by that?

Comment: await still waits the output from getTime function.